# Finding the conjugate/hermitian transpose of a transformation

Tags: transformation, transpose

Hopefully, I'm using the correct terms/names of things, mainly because the language in which I study is not English.

Given the operator $T$, in this case is the derivative operator , with the inner product:
$$
<f,g>=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cdot g(x)dx
$$
in vector space $V=\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ (polynomials with degree $\leq2$, in $[0,1]$)

Find the conjugate transpose operator $T^\ast$.

I'm aware that $T^\ast$ allows: $<T(v),u>=<v,T^\ast(u)>$ for all $u,v\in V$

After trying to play with the equation, I've got this:

let $f,g\in V$ such that:
$$
<T(f),g>=. . .=f\cdot g-<f,T(g)>=<f,T^\ast(g)>
$$

At this point I'm not sure how to extract $T^\ast$, so any direction of though is helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Bumping this, must be persistent in the hunt for knowledge and improvement.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Isn't $V$ just a finite vector space over $\mathbb{R}$? Can you not just write out the matrix for $T$ with your favorite basis, take the transpose, and see what it is? If not, pardon my ignorance.